# phonegap social sharing plugin hide post for facebook wall

Tags: html

I used this plugin for sharing any text on my Android mobile App https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

and every thing is ok, expect one thing

when I write some text and I want to share it, the plugin opens a list of sharing programs, and I can select any one and share the text that I wrote before, but if I select facebook sharing, it delete the text I wrote, and show to user an empty text area, and ignore the text that I called the plugin with

Any Suggestions???